# Python 3: Requests response.iter_content: ChunkedEncodingError

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, chunking

I am using requests **stream** for preforming a 'GET' download of a remote very large CSVs, then chunking response using `response.iter_content()`. This has been working for multiple data providers.

However, for one remote data provider, when using `response.iter_content()`, occasionally I am getting a `ChunkedEncodingError`, specifically:

```
ChunkedEncodingError: (
ProtocolError(
'Connection broken: IncompleteRead(921 bytes read, 103 more expected)',
IncompleteRead(921 bytes read, 103 more expected)),
)
```

Here is the `Python 3` code, and I would like to know of an alternative to resolving this chunking exception problem:

```
tmp_csv_chunk_sum = 0

with open(
    file=tmp_csv_file_path,
    mode='wb',
    encoding=encoding_write
) as csv_file_wb:
    try:
        for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=8192):
            if not chunk:
                break

            tmp_csv_chunk_sum += 8192

            csv_file_wb.write(chunk)
            csv_file_wb.flush()
            os.fsync(csv_file_wb.fileno())

    except Exception as ex:
        self.logger.error(
            "Request CSV Download: Exception",
            extra={
                'error_details': str(ex),
                'chunk_total_sum': tmp_csv_chunk_sum
            }
        )
        raise
```

I truly appreciate assistance, Thank you